# Deploy Upgradable contract with factory contract

Tags: blockchain, hardhat, smart-contract-wallets, openzeppelin-contracts, proxy-contracts

I have a simple contract below `Swap.sol` that is upgradable.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-or-later
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";

contract Swap is Initializable {

    address public tokenA;
    address public tokenB;

    function initialize(
        address _tokenA, 
        address _tokenB, 
    ) public initializer {
        tokenA = _tokenA;
        tokenB = _tokenB;

    }

 function getTokenA() public view returns (address) {
        return tokenA;
    }

}
```

And a factory contract that deploys multiple `Swap.sol` on call of `createSwap`.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >0.4.23 <0.9.0;
import "./Swap.sol";
contract SwapFactory {

    Swap[] private _swaps;

    function createSwap(address _tokenA, address _tokenB) public {
        Swap swap = new Swap();
        swap.initialize(_tokenA, _tokenB);
        _swaps.push(swap);
    }

    function getSwaps() public view returns (Swap[] memory)
    {
        return _swaps;
    }

}
```

When I deploy `SwapFactory` and call `createSwap` it says

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Initializable: contract is already initialized'
```

How do I solve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Contracts look fine.

Answer (score 0):

`public initializer` means it will only run only once at deploying